# Could not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3 npm

Tags: reactjs

While trying to install npm install , I am getting below error, could someone please advise, what is the best approach to resolve the problem. Due to this error, my build is getting failed in Heroku.

error: $

```
npm ERR! While resolving: react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.x" from @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@0.1.14
npm ERR!   node_modules/@fortawesome/react-fontawesome
npm ERR!     @fortawesome/react-fontawesome@"^0.1.14" from the root project
npm ERR!   4 more (@testing-library/react, react-dom, react-scripts, react-toastify)
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR! node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!   react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@16.14.0
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   peer react@"^15.0.0 || ^16.0.0" from react-typical@0.1.3
npm ERR!   node_modules/react-typical
npm ERR!     react-typical@"^0.1.3" from the root project
```

//package.json

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "proxy": "http://localhost:8080/",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.35",
    "@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-owl-carousel": "^2.3.3",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-toastify": "^7.0.4",
    "react-typical": "^0.1.3",
    "rxjs": "^7.2.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have tried

> npm config set legacy-peer-deps true
> npm i

but no fix yet.

Answer (score 0):

The `react-typical` library wants `React` to be version `15` or `16`. You're using `17`.

You could downgrade React which is not ideal:

`npm uninstall react && npm install react@16`

The `react-typical` library hasn't seen upgrades for 3+ years, so I'm not exactly sure what can be done other than contributing to the repository to refactor it to work for React 17,18+ - or finding another library that suits your needs.

I hope that helps out! Dealing with dependency issues can be hectic.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to assist me with my troubles! I really appreciate the help!